# Distribution of maximum Brownian motion conditional to natural filtration

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

While trying to solve a problem, I realized I might need to compute the distribution of $W_T^{*} = \sup_{t \leq T} W_t$ conditional to $\mathcal{F}_A$, where $T > A > 0$ is a deterministic time and $\mathcal{F}$ is the natural filtration of the Brownian motion $W$.

I would really appreciate any help on this one !
Thank you so much and have a wonderful new year's eve !

Comment: What exactly do you need to compute? It is, for instance, not too difficult to calculate $\mathbb{P}(W_T^* \leq x \mid \mathcal{F}_A)$ for fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! My short term goal is to find an integral representation of the expectation of $f(W_T^{*})$ conditional to $\mathcal{F}_A$ for any bounded, borelian function f.

Comment: It is possible to show that $$\mathbb{E}(f(W_T^*) \mid \mathcal{F}_A) = G(W_A^*,W_A)$$ where $$\begin{align*} G(x,y) &:= \mathbb{E}\left( f \left[ \min \left\{x, y+ \sup_{t \leq T-A} W_t \right\} \right] \right) \\ &=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi (T-A)}} \int_{u \geq 0} f \left( \min \left\{x, y+ u \right\} \right) \exp \left( - \frac{u^2}{2 (T-A)} \right) \, du. \end{align*}$$ Not sure whether this integral representation is helpful for you...

Comment: Thank you for this nice integral form, which shows that I won't be able to proceed with my business any further ! 

Despite this fact, do you have any guidance on how to show this ? Even small pointers would be much appreciated as I understand that the proof can be quite painful to write in LaTeX.

Comment: See my answer below for details (in my previous comment it was supposed to read "max" instead of "min"...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$$W_T^* = \max \left\{W_A^*, W_A+ \sup_{0 \leq t \leq T-A} (W_{t+A}-W_A) \right\}$$

we have

$$\mathbb{E}(f(W_T^*) \mid \mathcal{F}_A) = \mathbb{E} \left( f \left[ \max \left\{W_A^*, W_A+ \sup_{t \leq T-A} (W_{t+A}-W_A) \right\} \right] \mid \mathcal{F}_A \right).$$

The random variables $W_A$ and $W_A^*$ are $\mathcal{F}_A$-measurable and the process $$B_t := W_{t+A}-W_A$$ is independent from $\mathcal{F}_A$; therefore, we obtain

$$\mathbb{E}(f(W_T^*) \mid \mathcal{F}_A) = \mathbb{E} \left( f \left[ \max \left\{x, y+ \sup_{t \leq T-A} B_t \right\} \right] \right) \bigg|_{x=W_A^*, y=W_A}. \tag{1}$$

The restarted process $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion and therefore we know from the reflection principle that

$$\sup_{t \leq T-A} B_t \sim |B_{T-A}|.$$

Since $B_{T-A}$ is Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $T-A$, we obtain

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(f(W_T^*) \mid \mathcal{F}_A) &= \mathbb{E}(f[\max\{x,y+|B_{T-A}|\}]) \bigg|_{x=W_A^*,y=W_A} \\ &= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi(T-A)}} \int_{u \geq 0} f(\max\{W_A^*,W_A+u\}) \exp \left(- \frac{u^2}{2(T-A)} \right) \, du. \end{align*}$$

Comment: This is a crystal clear proof, thank you very much !

Comment: @M3ktn You are welcome.